# jsTree: bind keypress event on a newly created node

Tags: jstree, addeventlistener, onkeypress

I am trying to bind keypress event on a newly created node from context menu of jsTree. It seems adding listener for each and every node is not so good idea..Edited as per suggestion based on comments provided below

```
$(function () {
        $('#demo').jstree({
             ...
              "contextmenu":{         
                    "items": function($node) {
                        var tree = $("#demo").jstree(true);
                        return {
                            "Create": {
                                "separator_before": false,
                                "separator_after": false,
                                "label": "Create",
                                "action": function (obj) { 
                                    var newNode = createNode($node,tree);
                                    //tree.edit(newNode);

                        tree.edit(newNode, null, function (the_node, rename_status) {

                            console.log("status:"+rename_status);
                        });
                                   }
                            }
                            }
                        };
                    }
                }

            })
    });




function createNode($node,tree)
   {
      $newNode = tree.create_node($node); //create new node
      return $newNode;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jstree `create_node` functions does not return a DOM node, it returns an ID string, as stated here: http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=create_node&f=create_node%28[obj,%20node,%20pos,%20callback,%20is_loaded]%29

In order to be able to attach any event you need the DOM node, so rewrite your `createNode` function to this:

```
function createNode($node,tree) {
    $newNode = tree.create_node($node); //create new node
    return tree.get_node($newNode, true);
}
```

*Also keep in mind if you attach a handler like this, it will be lost if the parent of this node is closed and then opened, as jstree keeps only visible nodes in the DOM. If that is not OK for you - use event delegation, for example by attaching the event to the tree container.*

---

As per the comments below, a better solution would be to use the `edit` callback (provided you are using jstree v.3.1.1 or later):

```
tree.edit(newNode, null, function (the_node, rename_status) {
  // any custom logic you need
})
```

---

Here is the final demo using the edit callback and v.3.1.1:
http://jsfiddle.net/DGAF4/498/

If using an earlier version OR you do not care about catching calls to `rename_node` - listen for the `rename_node.jstree` event - this is the preferred method to react to name changes.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info, I will go with second approach as first one seems to be bit confusing for end user. I have edited in my post above. The keypress event is triggered but somehow it does not recognise enter key so the alert is never fired in my case...Do you have any ideas what have i missed out ?

Comment: The enter key is captured by the rename input text box (displayed when you call `edit`). I need to ask - what are you trying to accomplish? Bind an event on each and every node, or only on the rename input text box?

Comment: i am trying to bind event on each and every node so when create_node is accomplished , i have to send the name  of newly created node (when the enter is pressed) to server at the same time

Comment: Then why don't you use the `rename_node` event, or to better suit your needs - the newly added `edit` callback. I am modifying my answer to include this.

Comment: yes i m using v3.1.1. i added this edit callback right after var newNode = createNode($node,tree); But this edit does not seem to be triggered. it does not give any errors in console .

Comment: I just added a demo to the original answer - the last fiddle

Comment: I used rename_node event and got the newly created nodes name/id. for now..It is bit strange that edit call back is not working(I have also set check callback as true). But Thanks for all the support !

Comment: Is it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/DGAF4/498/ ? If it is - then you must be using an older version and not 3.1.1 in your code. I also edited my answer to include the `rename_node.jstree` event (if you'd like to accept it).

Comment: Oh My mistake. Yes i downloaded latest jsTree plugin and edit call back is working . THank you so much!!